# Cannot remove an observer for the key path "delegate" from because it is not registered as an observer for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am developing iPhone/iPad Calendar application and I am using the SACalendar.h third party class and I also have a side menu. When moving from one view to another view I am getting error like this:

> Error :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
>   reason: 'Cannot remove an observer  for the key
>   path "delegate" from  because it is not
>   registered as an observer.'

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Simply try @ try {
        }
        @ catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"%@",exception);
        }
        @ finally {
            
        }

Comment: Create an exception breakpoint.  When your app hits the breakpoint, copy the stack trace and paste it into your question.